# Stardew Valley autohotkey script

Tags: autohotkey

I have a problem with my autohotkey script for stardew. I for some reason can't get it to cast for me on button 4.I currently have this code which by all account should work:

```
#IfWinActive Stardew Valley

XButton1::
SendInput, {LButton Down}
KeyWait, LButton, T1.0248
SendInput, {LButton Up}
Return
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect it to do? You can't expect us to know `Stardew Valley` and a `cast` is.

Comment: @Forivin So the problem isn't that it doesn't work but "#IfWinActive Stardew Valley" doesn't get caught. I can't seem to get any window one working on my computer for anything though even though I have followed every guide. Windows 10 OS. Any idea for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have problems with `#IfWinActive`, then you probably haven't entered the window name that AutoHotkey is seeing. Use the WindowSpy utility from your AutoHotkey installation folder to find the correct window name.
Alternatively you could try using `#IfWinActive ahk_exe proccessname.exe`.

And if your game runs as admin, then you might have to run your script as admin too.

Comment: I used the windowspy but there might be a problem with me using mods for it. I'll double check when I'm home. I'll check the admin idea as well.

Comment: So none of these work:
Stardew Valley - Version 1.11 | SMAPI 1.8
ahk_class WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.fb11c8_r9_ad1
ahk_exe StardewModdingAPI.exe

I've also checked and the game is not run as admin

Comment: So it suddenly started working without me changing anything. Thanks for the suggestions though. Very helpful ideas.